# Symfony 5 Phpunit undefined method

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm working with Symfony 5 and I installed phpunit-bridge with the command included in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#the-phpunit-testing-framework) : `composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge`.

When I run phpunit with this command, `php bin/phpunit`, I have this error :

> PHP Fatal error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner::doRun()

Comment: Please share more details.

Comment: Ok, what kind of details?

Comment: Just start with anything. This is such a standard way of running PHPUnit that I can't imagine it's broken for everyone. But as you haven't shown anything (like: an environment where anybody could reproduce the problem), it's close to impossible to provide any hint

Comment: I'm working with Symfony 5.0 and Windows 7. I installed symfony/phpunit-bridge with this comand : composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge. When I run php bin/phpunitI  to install PHPUnit, I have this error :C:\cmder\roadtrip>php bin/phpunit
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner::doRun() in C:\cmder\roadtrip\bin\.phpunit\phpunit-7.5-0\src\TextUI\Command.php:206

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to guess.

You also have a bundle like `liip/functional-test-bundle` or other, which require PHPUnit in requirements (or even you require PHPUnit directly in your `composer.json` together with `phpunit-bridge`).

As a result you have two different version of PHPUnit installed in project, with two different api.

If installed `liip/functional-test-bundle` is your case and you do not want to remove it, you need to install by bridge same PHPUnit version as installed by Liip bundle dependency. You can set version through `SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION` env variable or directly in `bin/phpunit` file. Or you can redefine path to already installed PHPUnit version (in vendors/) through `SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_DIR` env or directly in `bin/phpunit`.

**Note**: you can not set `SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION` or `SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_DIR` through .env.* files, since `bin/phpunit` not read this files. So it should be real env vars.

Comment: I many times installed and uninstalled orm-fixtures, phpunit, liip/tests and symfony/phpunit-bridge. Now, it's working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with **symfony 5.1**. I tried upgrading all dev packages related to testing but it didn't work.
Once I completely remove all dev (testing related) packages and reinstalling the symfony phpunit bridge package it worked.
**You have to remove the phpunit file inside the root/bin directory**

**Steps to follow**

1. Remove all dev test packages (Eg: `composer remove symfony/browser-kit`)
2. Remove if there are following packages : phpunit/phpunit, symfony/phpunit-bridge, symfony/css-selector, symfony/browser-kit
3. Install the brdge package again by running  `composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge`